# getbufvar function when called from a plugin or vimrc returns empty string

Tags: vim

I have a plugin where I call getbufvar inside one of the plugin functions to check if a buffer is a quckfixlist. getbufvar always return empty string. However if I pass a hardcoded value like 1 as buffer number instead of a variable it returns the correct string. Is it a bug in getbufvar?

Below is a test code to reproduce.

```
function! Test(bufNum)
  return getbufvar(a:bufNum, '&ft')
endfunction

au BufEnter * echoerr expand('<abuf>'). ", ". Test(expand('<abuf>'))
```

The above snippet echos '1,' when I a open a python file. However, If I call getbufvar(1, '&ft') it prints '1, python'. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VimScript strings and numbers differ in runtime. `expand()` always returns a string, but `getbufvar()` expects either buffer name (`v:t_string`) or buffer number (`v:t_number`). So "1" is interpreted (by argument type) as buffer name. You must cast it to number to avoid this trouble.

But note that in this instance `BufEnter` is always called *after* entering a buffer, so you can safely use `bufnr()` (or even simply `&ft` without `getbufvar()`).

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I wish the vim help page was more clearer about this

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem comes from the `<abuf>` here, you might want to use the `buffer_number()` function instead